# How do I login as a windows non-admin from Admin account without a password

Tags: windows, admin

I administer a small windows domain for my in-law's family business. I regularly need to install software for their users, and then I want to test it as a non-administrator user. My question is as a windows admin, how can switch to the user account without needing their password?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot! Create a non-Admin dummy account only for your use, which only you will have access to check if non-Admin rights are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you cannot become another user without logging on (via password or other credentials such as fingerprints).

There is a discussion of a very similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16886/is-there-an-equivalent-of-su-for-windows).

Also, you may want to consider the effects of [user account control (UAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) which displays a prompt as soon as a process needs elevated privileges, even if run as a privileged user (unless the application meets certain requirements such as being digitally signed). See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/628731/least-privileges-run-cmd-as-standard-user-from-a-privileged-account-no-pas).